# How to set session attribute in java?

Tags: java, jsp

I am able to set session attribute in scriptlet  but when I am trying to set session attribute inside java class it shows error like "session cannot be resolved".
So how to set session in java?

```
<%String username = (String)request.getAttribute("un");
session.setAttribute("UserName", username);%>
```

Comment: i hope you write this code in a .jsp class.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

By Java class, I am assuming you mean a Servlet class as setting session attribute in arbitrary Java class does not make sense.You can do something like this in your servlet's doGet/doPost methods

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String username = (String)request.getAttribute("un");
    session.setAttribute("UserName", username);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default session object is available on jsp page(implicit object). It will not available in normal POJO java class.
You can get the reference of HttpSession object on Servelt by using HttpServletRequest

```
HttpSession s=request.getSession()
s.setAttribute("name","value");
```

You can get session on an ActionSupport based Action POJO class as follows

```
 ActionContext ctx= ActionContext.getContext();
   Map m=ctx.getSession();
   m.put("name", value);
```

look at:
http://ohmjavaclasses.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-session-in-action-class-struts2.html

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
<%@page language="java" session="true" %>
```

Answer (score -3):

I am try to catch your point.I hope it is helpful.....

```
if (session.isNew()){
     title = "Welcome to my website";
     session.setAttribute(userIDKey, userID);
```

Answer (score -7):

### Java file : Jclass.java

```
package Jclasspackage

public class Jclass {

    public String uname ;
    /**
     * @return the uname
     */
    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    /**
     * @param uname the uname to set
     */
    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public Jclass() {
        this.uname = null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

### JSP file: sample.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java"
    import="java.util.*,java.io.*"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<jsp:directive.page import="Jclasspackage.Jclass.java" />   
<% Jclass jc = new Jclass();
String username = (String)request.getAttribute("un")
jc.setUname(username);
%>
```

### -----------------

In this way you can access the username in the java file using 
"this.username" in the class

Comment: Pawan, how is long example relevant to setting a **session** attribute?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki This is just an alternate way of implementing the functionality.

Comment: I don't think this is - it's accessing your POJO and using **request scoped** attribute to set it's property. It has nothing to do with **session**.