# how to use a variable's value throughout session in servlet/jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I doing some project based on authentication using servlet/jsp.When user log in initially using username and password where authentication takes place through login servlet,there I need to save user's email in variable ,say `String email` by executing `SELECT` query.
I need to access that variable from login servlet to email servlet for sending some sort of OTP to user's email.
How to achieve that using session attribute or any relevant idea??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set session attribute in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292940/how-to-set-session-attribute-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `session.setAttribute()` and `session.getAttribute()` methods.

Read javadoc of HttpSession [here](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

You can refer [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/session_api.shtml) complete example.

Answer (score 1):

please use as follows. you can achieve what you need.

```
 <%session.setAttribute( "email", "test@gmail.com" );%>
 <%= session.getAttribute( "email" ) %>
```

The other way that we use.

```
 <c:set var="email" value="test@gmail.com" scope="session"/>
```

you get this using JS:

```
var mail ="${email}";
```

Answer (score 1):

To save data in session you should use session object from http request like this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("email", email);
```

To retrieve data from session object with scriptlet use:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("email")%>
```

or

```
<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("email")%>
```

You can also use EL expression:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:out value="${sessionScope.email}"/>
```